# Hiding Country Specific Fields

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012

I have the following problem.

The LogisticsPostalAddress form is displaying the StreetInKana field. (this holds special characters used in Japan". The underlying EDT extends an EDT which has 'JPN' in the CountryRegionCodes property. The company I am using has primary address with country'GBR'. My understanding is that this should mean the field would be hidden, but it is not. So far we have made very few changes to standard AX code, and nothing that would be related. So either I have set something up wrong, or these fields are meant to be displayed, which would surprise me. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to change the property `CountryRegionContextField` of the corresponding control to point to the field which has `CountryRegionCodes` value set (either on table level, or EDT level).

I guess you have to explicitly set this property because you can have different forms with the same table as data source, but restrict access only on some of them.

Comment: That works thanks, though I'm a bit disappointed that it didn't default from the EDT